# LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

I have 2 apps which requir to login. But I dont know really how to set redirections for each app. I was following tutorial and both were using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, for one app it works excelent but for many it gives problem. When I press login in my "ecommerce" app, is redirecting me to "blog app" homepage as it's set in setting.py. How can I change redirections for each app? Or should I create new views for login ?

My views from Blog:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterFrom(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login {username}!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterFrom()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

My views from ecommerce:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()

            login(request, user)

            vendor = Vendor.objects.create(name=user.username, created_by=user)

            return redirect('frontpage')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'vendor/become_vendor.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def vendor_admin(request):
    vendor = request.user.vendor
    products = vendor.products.all()
    orders = vendor.orders.all()

    for order in orders:
        order.vendor_amount = 0
        order.vendor_paid_amount =0
        order.full_paid = True

        for item in order.items.all():
            if item.vendor == request.user.vendor:
                if item.vendor_paid:
                    order.vendor_paid_amount += item.get_total_price()
                else:
                    order.vendor_amount += item.get_total_price()
                    order.full_paid = False

    return render(request, 'vendor/vendor_admin.html', {'vendor': vendor, 'products': products, 'orders': orders})
```

My ulrs from ecommerce:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='vendor/login.html'), name='loggin'),
```

My ulrs from blog:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
```

Comment: Please mention the urls (add their url patterns) you want to redirect to from the respective login views.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Can you explain me what exactly do you mean ? Do you want me to show you my both porjects urls ? Im beginner in programing.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default `LoginView` such that you can easily customize it for usage in both of your url patterns like so. Note that the below feature is already present in Django's main branch on GitHub and will likely be released in Django 4.0:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url

class LoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    next_page = None
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.get_redirect_url() or self.get_default_redirect_url()
    
    def get_default_redirect_url(self):
        """Return the default redirect URL."""
        return resolve_url(self.next_page or settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

Next in your urlpatterns you can import this view and set a value `next_page` for in the `as_view` method of the the view to configure which url the user should be redirected to after login:

In your ulrs from `ecommerce` app (Replace `some_view_name` with the name of the pattern you want to redirect to):

```
from path.to import LoginView # import from where you wrote the class
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='vendor/login.html', next_page=reverse_lazy('some_view_name')), name='loggin'),
```

Similarly for `blog` app (Replace `some_other_view_name` with the name of the pattern you want to redirect to):

```
from path.to import LoginView # import from where you wrote the class
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html', next_page=reverse_lazy('some_other_view_name')), name='login'),
```

---

> **Note**: Instead of giving weird names to url patterns to avoid name clashes (`loggin` to avoid name clash with `login`) consider
> [namespacing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)
> your urls.

Comment: I just changed everything as you show me the example and commeneted redirect from settings for now and having this error...
raise TypeError("%s() received an invalid keyword %r. as_view "
TypeError: LoginView() received an invalid keyword 'next_page'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.

Comment: can you help me now with this one please ?

Comment: @ArturJasiński my bad, `next_page` seems to be an unreleased feature I saw from Django's GitHub repo. Check my edit for a solution

Comment: I just copied entire class and pasted it in views which is located in same direcotry as my urls.  Then "from .views import LoginView in ulrs.py still having the same error..

Comment: @ArturJasiński are you sure you are importing the correct view, and if so you get the same error in your comment above? My class does declare the attribute `next_page` so that shouldn't be happening if you use it.

Comment: I did something wrong on the way to implement it. I tried it 2nd time and now everything is working as I wanted to !!!! Thanks a lot ! you are the best !