# Django external authentication (allauth) redirect to diffrent locations with diffrent providers

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

I have three ways to sign in (github, google, reddit).
I want to redirect individually after login with these different providers.
Right now it redirects all types of login to this location:
`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`
How to specify different locations for different providers?

My LoginView:

```
def loginView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f'Welcome {user}')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            arg = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', arg)
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    arg = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `get_default_redirect_url` method of LoginView

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67960468/10098655) answer

Comment: Can you help me override it?
I've added my loginView.

Comment: to override this method you need to convert your loginView method to class base.